# Linking a DLL in an Unreal 4 Plugin

Tags: c++, dll, linker, unreal-engine4

So I am writing a plugin that will be using some `.dll` `.lib` packages. I've successfully got the plugin's `Build.cs` to include the `.lib` but it wont compile. I get an `external symbol not found` error that just wont go away. I've placed the `.dll` at all the locations I can think of where the linker should pick it up to no avail (Binary folders in and out of the plugin, (Win64 and "ThirdParty")), Public and Private Folders in the plugin, project root, you name it.

Does anyone know how to link a `.dll` for use in a plugin? (fyi, I just want to expose part of the `.dll` to Blueprints or use them in C++ functions that get exposed to Blueprints).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know that your Build.cs includes the .lib file?

Also, you can not include just every lib file, it has to be compiled with the correct compiler options or the linker will not like it (see [here](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Linking_Static_Libraries_Using_The_Build_System)).
Adding DLLs is more complicated than adding libs, because you have to do it at runtime: https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Linking_Dlls

Comment: Well if I remove the `.lib` as an `AdditionalDependency` in `Build.cs` I get more compiler errors, so I know its being found. I've successfully linked `.DLL`s in Unreal before, but in the project proper, not in a plugin.

Comment: Sorry, I completely jumped over the part that your problem is within a plugin! I never developed a plugin myself, so I think I won't be of much help. I assume you already tried the unreal answerhub?

Comment: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/189978/linking-a-dll-in-a-plugin.html dead as a doornail.